# Unable to stop an input field from auto-populating

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm running into a strange issue with a simple input field rendered through the material-ui library (called `TextField` in the library). I'm somehow unable to prevent it from auto-populating even upon page refresh! Here's the component props:

```
<TextField
      {...{
        id: 'emailField',
        placeholder,
        error,
        type,
        fullWidth,
        disabled,
        required,
        variant: 'outlined',
        className: classes.margin,
        label: 'Email',
        name,
        helperText,
        ...(value && { value }),
      }}
      autoComplete='off'
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start"><EmailIcon /></InputAdornment>,
      }}
    />
```

And this is the HTML it renders:

```
<input aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="emailField-helper-text" autocomplete="off" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart MuiOutlinedInput-inputAdornedStart" id="emailField" name="userid" placeholder="&quot;john@doe.com&quot; or &quot;johndoe123&quot;" required="" type="text" value="">
```

If you notice, it does render with the `autocomplete="off"` attribute as expected. However, it still doesn't stop the field from getting pre-populated with a value I had used before even after the page is refreshed. FWIW, am using Chrome and this does not happen when I load the page in incognito mode.

The page is live at https://www.schandillia.com.

Comment: I am running your site on Chrome and it is not auto populating as you claim to. Any steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I managed to fix it with an `autocomplete="username email"` and `autocomplete="new-password"`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have tried so many things.  new-password worked like a charm!